# How do I create a new branch?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch

How do I create a new branch with my working copy using TortoiseSVN?

I see the branch option, but I don't see a way to name it somehow.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Branches in SVN are essentially directories; you don't name the branch so much as choose the name of the directory to branch into.

The common way of 'naming' a branch is to place it under a directory called `branches` in your repository. In the "To URL:" portion of TortoiseSVN's Branch dialog, you would therefore enter something like:

```
(svn/http)://path-to-repo/branches/your-branch-name
```

The main branch of a project is referred to as the *trunk*, and is usually located in:

```
(svn/http)://path-to-repo/trunk
```

Comment: Now why do I get: "OPTIONS of 'http://subversion2/svn/DanelNursing4/branches/Omer': Could not read 
status line: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Comment: Isn't "To URL:" now "To path:"?

Answer (score 240):

Right click and open SVN Repo-browser:

[image]

Right click on Trunk (working copy) and choose *Copy to...*:

[image]

Input the respective branch's name/path:

[image]

Click OK, type the respective log message, and click OK.

Comment: After this step, if you want to access the files of the revision, get  the right click menu of the tags/branch folder. choose: SVN Update. Only then, the folder of Version2.45.5 is copied with its files in the folder.

Comment: "Copy to... "  does not appear on my menu - Versio n1.9.5 Build 27581

Comment: @NealWalters - this may vary on the Windows SVN client you are using. On mine, I have "SVN Branch/Tag". If you don't see that either, then check go into the settings of your SVN client and check what options are enabled for the "Context Menu".

Answer (score 66):

In the Repository Browser of TortoiseSVN, find the branch that you want to create the new branch from. Right-click, Copy To.... and enter the new branch path. Now you can "switch" your local WC to that branch.

Answer (score 12):

My solution if you work with the `Trunk/` and `Release/` workflow:

Right click on `Trunk/` which you will be creating your Branch from:

[image: Trunk]

Select Branch/Tag:

[image: Branch/Tag]

Type in location of your new branch, commit message, and any externals (if your repository has them):

[image]