# Tortoise SVN: Creating a Sparse Branch

Tags: extjs, tortoisesvn, branch, sparse-checkout

Below is a link with instructions on how to create a branch using Tortoise SVN.

[How do I create a new branch using TortoiseSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059870/how-to-create-a-new-branch-using-tortoisesvn)

I'm using the Sencha ExtJS and Sencha Touch frameworks for my development.  Sencha recommends that developers structure your app trunk folders as children (or descendant) folders to the actual framework itself, so each app can share packages and themes, as well as the framework resources (ie: images, icons, etc...).

**SVN project folder structure:**

```
svn_folder\branches\
svn_folder\tags\
svn_folder\trunk\
```

**trunk folder structure:**

```
svn_folder\trunk\.sencha\...
svn_folder\trunk\ext\...
svn_folder\trunk\packages\...
svn_folder\trunk\app1\...
svn_folder\trunk\app2\...
```

**Just bring app1 over to new branch:**

```
svn_folder\branches\app1_1.1\...
```

Because this workflow above (to create a branch) says to copy the trunk to the new branch folder, all of the apps are being copied.  Essentially I'd like to pick the apps I'd like to copy over.  Tortoise has a way to do this using the sparse checkout functionality.  Does anyone know what the workflow would be to do this when creating a branch?

Comment: JFYI: it will be easier and faster in CLI-way

Comment: What does CLI stand for?

Comment: "Command Line Interface"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I don't get too many answers here is because SVN is ancient.  Git is the new age of version control.  I'm moving all of my code to GitHub (for public accounts and paid private accounts) and BitBucket (for free private accounts).

Comment: SVN is popular enough that it is supported for VisualStudio for MacOS.