# SVN branching failed

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch

I tried to branch from a trunk into a folder I just created in Tortoise repository browser. I have followed this guide: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html

Unfortunatelly I keep getting an error:
File not found: transaction '9361-7do', path

I've searched net WO answer and this does not answer either:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tortoisesvn/5md5KQAURaE

Could the problem be I don't have rights for branching ?
Could it be that I did not specify dest. directory: ../branch/
as it says here: [How do I create a new branch using TortoiseSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059870/how-to-create-a-new-branch-using-tortoisesvn)  ?

Comment: I also tried right click on Source Folder in RepoBrowser -> Copy to -> set dest. folder.

This time I did not get any error, but success message neiter ...

After repoBrowser refresh I could see, the files were copied. Its a very stange behavior. Unless I did something wrong above (most probably), then it seems like an svn bug. But I never had these problems with svn branching 2+ years ago.

Comment: Did you actually fill in a full, existing path to do the branch with you first attempt? Or did you copy the example and use something like "/tags/blah" for your path?

Comment: Ben: I am sure the path was OK..
The problem seems to be connected more to insufficient rights for branching. When I used admin account, I could copy to a new path.